# Is it possible to submit a form by triggering Enter with only javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

There ist a Form and Input without a button. You can send a message by typing Enter.
The Form has an id.

Is it possible to trigger or kinda faking the Enter-Key only with JavaScript? (No jQuery, because the Page has already been loaded).

I tried:

```
e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13; //choose the one you want
document.querySelector("gui.frm_chat.tabs.tab_6.text.input#main").keypress().trigger(e);
```

But it didn't have jQuery.

[image]

Comment: Start by testing you have the actual form. For example use `const $form = $("[id^='gui.frm_chat.tabs.tab_6.text.input']");`

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-eventType-extraParameters), `.trigger` just sends an event, so you can dispatch an event with the same parameters as your JQuery.Event (i.e your `e` variable).

Comment: Like I told. No jQuery installed. I tried with javascript: (function(e, s) {
    e.src = s;
    e.onload = function() {
        jQuery.noConflict();
        console.log('jQuery injected');
    };
    document.head.appendChild(e);
})(document.createElement('script'), '//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'); But it didn't really work.

Comment: Created events like with e.g. `new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { code: 'Enter', key: 'Enter', keyCode: 13, which: 13 })` are not trusted. Thus triggering such an event via `dispatchEvent` is not followed by the expected action.

Answer (score 0):

I think `form.submit()` is what you are looking for:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp

Comment: Nope, I tried that already, but it just open a new Tab or reload the page. But a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the better solution is `form.requestSubmit()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit

Comment: Okay I will try

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. It seems that there is no submit buttons:
VM733:6 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'requestSubmit' on 'HTMLFormElement': The specified element is not a submit button.
    at <anonymous>:6:12

Comment: That's kind of weird and seems to be an implementation bug of the user agent you are using. `requestSubmit()` can accept an argument beeing the submit button you want, but it needn't. What user agent do you use?

Comment: Mhhh, just http-request with a chrome browser... Submit kinda works, or it reacts to, but don't send it... But it kinda helps me to know where to debug!

Comment: It already send by clicking "Enter" in the background. But how can I fake it without clicking on Enter?

Comment: Okay, just tried a small form myself and sending it with `requestSubmit()` and everything went fine. I used Vivaldi (chromium based) for testing. Therefore I think there is something else wrong with it.